# Getting first string from string array in c

Tags: c, arrays, string, string-concatenation

I am trying to create processes for my project. I will pas arguments to child process from parent and the argument will change in time, so i wanted to make a try first with passing 1 to the child. The string format should be like this "childname.exe c" where c represents random character (in this case it is 1 for just trial).

I created a childname array and and all i wanted was concatenate the new string with childname string and copy it to another string array(lpCommandLine variable). When i debugged the code below i saw that child_name[0] (when i is equal to 0) returns only 'C' although i expected it to return "ChildProj1.exe". Is there a point that i missed or how to do it in c?

here there is a image of what i getin debugger: [here stored values of in variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vIBZQ.jpg)

```
#define NO_OF_PROCESS 3

char *child_names[]= {"ChildProj1.exe", "ChildProj2.exe", "ChildProj3.exe" };
char* lpCommandLine[NO_OF_PROCESS];
int i;

    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_PROCESS; i++)
        lpCommandLine[i] = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 16);


    for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_PROCESS; i++)
    {
        strcat_s(child_names[i], strlen(child_names[i]), " 1");
        strcpy_s(lpCommandLine[i], strlen(lpCommandLine[i]), child_names[i]);
    }
```

Comment: where do you think the new string "<childproces> 1" is going to be stored. strcat_s failed becuase you tried to add characters to the buffer - check the return value of srcat_s

Comment: @Y.E.S.  It is unclear what you are going to get in the array    lpCommandLine. Show its result content.

Comment: I want it to be stored in lpCommandLine. In child_names array 0th string is "ChildProj1.exe" and i want lpCommandLine[0] to be "ChildProj1.exe 1".  So do you suggest to allocate memory for each child_names indexes for 16 chars which means ChildProj1.exe + 3 (for blank and 1 and \0)

Comment: @vlad-from-moscow it is not necessary to know what i am trying to do with lpCommandLine array. All i want is concatenate " 1" with strings of array child_names and copy each string to lpCommandLine array.

Comment: @Y.E.S. It seems I have understood what you want. See my answer.:)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your description it follows that you want to get strings like this

```
"childname.exe c"
```

However this loop

```
for (i = 0; i < NO_OF_PROCESS; i++)
{
    strcat_s(child_names[i], strlen(child_names[i]), " 1");
    strcpy_s(lpCommandLine[i], strlen(lpCommandLine[i]), child_names[i]);
}
```

does not do what you want.

This loop has undefined behavior because in this statement

```
    strcat_s(child_names[i], strlen(child_names[i]), " 1");
```

there is an attempt to modify a string literal. You may not change string literals neither in C nor in C++.

Moreover in this statement

```
    strcpy_s(lpCommandLine[i], strlen(lpCommandLine[i]), child_names[i]);
```

this call

```
strlen(lpCommandLine[i])
```

also has undefined behavior because array pointed to by this pointer `lpCommandLine[i]` does not has the terminating zero.

There is no any need to use the functions `strcat_s` and `strcpy_s`. It is much better to use standard function `strcat` and `strcpy`.

What you is the following that is shown in this demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define NO_OF_PROCESS   3

int main(void) 
{
    const char * child_names[]= 
    {
        "ChildProj1.exe", 
        "ChildProj2.exe", 
        "ChildProj3.exe" 
    };

    const char *s = " 1";
    size_t n = strlen( s );

    char* lpCommandLine[NO_OF_PROCESS];

    for ( int i = 0; i < NO_OF_PROCESS; i++ )
    {
        lpCommandLine[i] = ( char * )malloc( strlen( child_names[i] ) + n + 1 );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < NO_OF_PROCESS; i++ )
    {
        strcpy( lpCommandLine[i], child_names[i] );
        strcat( lpCommandLine[i],  s );
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < NO_OF_PROCESS; i++ ) puts( lpCommandLine[i] );

for ( int i = 0; i < NO_OF_PROCESS; i++ ) free( lpCommandLine[i] );

    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
ChildProj1.exe 1
ChildProj2.exe 1
ChildProj3.exe 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `char * child_names[]` did you mean something like `char[][] child_names`, `char[] * child_names`, or `char ** child_names`?

Comment: I want to store strings in that array, already tried char[ ][ ], char** but didn't work.

Comment: with char* child_names[ ], i tried to print each element and it printed correctly with this code `printf("%s", child_names[i]);`. It prints each string like this but when i want to do concatenating things go crazy.

Answer (score 0):

to do the string concat do

```
size_t sz = strlen(child_names[i]) + 3; // space, '1' and \0
char *buff = malloc(sz); 
strcat_s(buff,sz,child_names[i]);
strcat_s(buff,sz," 1");
```

Comment: your issue about childname[0] = 'C' is a red herring. YOu just need to display it as a string rather than a char in the debugger

Comment: I just tried it now and in buff there is only "\0" it says. If you have time you can try it with your compiler, i wonder if there is a problem with my compiler now.